# Repeated string stick with the command before

Tags: linux, sed, awk

My input:

```
$ cat file ABC
ABC   
DEF  
DEF   
ABC   
GHI   
GHI   
DEF
```

The output that I want:

```
ABC_1   +FIXED  +outcome
ABC_2   +FIXED  +outcome
DEF_3   +FIXED  +outcome
DEF_4   +FIXED  +outcome
ABC_5   +FIXED  +outcome
GHI_6   +FIXED  +outcome
GHI_7   +FIXED  +outcome
DEF_8   +FIXED  +outcome
```

How can I print out the output by using `awk` command `?`

I tried using `awk -F " "'{print $1"_"++c}' ,?  ,?} file ABC`

How can I use `?` to handle repeated strings?

Comment: `awk '{print $1"_"++c " +FIXED +outcome"}'  file` ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
$ awk '{print $0"_"++c" +FIXED +outcome"}' test
DEF_1 +FIXED +outcome
DEF_2 +FIXED +outcome
ABC_3 +FIXED +outcome
GHI_4 +FIXED +outcome
GHI_5 +FIXED +outcome
DEF_6 +FIXED +outcome
```